# Import code child_process to Aurelia with RequireJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, aurelia, child-process

I have been trying to import "child_process" inside of my electron-aurelia project but with no success. 
So far I have tryied:

```
const ChildProcess = require('child_process');
```

and

```
import * as ChildProcess for "child_process"
```

but none of the above work. The first one returns the following error:

```
Error: Module name "child_process" has not been loaded yet for context:
```

and the second returns error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND          child_process.js
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Thank you